# Android gallery auto scroll with threshold values

Tags: android

I have created a custom gallery in which I have implemented the drag and drop mechanism and rearranged the items.Drag happens during a long click event and fling also works fine.Now my problem is I am trying to **auto scroll my gallery during a drag operation** when a particular threshold value is reached on the left and side of the gallery,for this i tried using **scrollto, setselection** both of them seems to be working weird,can somebody help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
myGallery.setSelection(position);
```

Try :

```
myGallery.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myGallery.setSelection(position);
    }
});
```

The same thing with `scrollTo` should also work.
I hope it will help you.